# ld with -Ttext=0x1000 makes the file very big

Tags: assembly, gcc, linker, operating-system, ld

I have `kernel.c` file looks like this

```
void main() {
    char *video_memory = (char *)0xb8000;
    *video_memory = 'X';
}
```

I compiled and linked with these 2 commands:

```
gcc -ffreestanding -c ./src/kernel/kernel.c -o kernel.o -m32 -mtune=i386 -fno-pie
ld -o kernel.bin -Ttext=0x1000 kernel.o --oformat binary -m elf_i386 --strip-all -nmagic
```

It produced a 128MB kernel.bin
However, when I remove `-Ttext=0x1000` in `ld` command, it produced a 120B kernel.bin.

If I understand correctly, `-Ttext=0x1000` will add offset `0x1000` to all memory reference. Why did it make such a big difference?

Comment: If you pick a different output format, like the default ELF, what addresses does it pick for the various sections or segments with `-Ttext=0x1000`?  (Use `readelf -a`).  I'm guessing there are two things a long way from each other, and a flat binary just pads with zeros to fill the gap.  Yeah, I tried it, and there's a read-only non-exec segment at `0x080480d4` (about 128MiB from 0x1000), holding the `.note.gnu.property` section.

Comment: IDK how to get rid of that or I'd post this as an answer, but check the manual; a linker script would work but maybe a way to just filter sections.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Adding this to linker script would do the job
`/DISCARD/ : {
  *(.note.gnu.property)
}`

Comment: first off do not build to binary just yet, build to elf.  then use readelf or objdump or other to show where the loadable sections are.  If you have one at say 0x00000000 and it has 1 byte and one at 0x1000000 and it has one byte then it is going to pad 0x0FFFFFF bytes and create a 0x10000001 byte file.  But if you have one thing at 0x10000000 and one byte at 0x10001000 then it will make a 0x1001 byte file with whatever padding needed.  the -O binary (objcopy) has to start at the lowest address of the sections and fills in and pads to the highest. to create the ouptput

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the comment of @Peter Cordes and @old_timer.

Building it to elf first and using `readelf -a`, I found that there is a segment at `0x080480d4` (about 128MB from 0x1000) holding `.note.gnu.property`.

So I add this linker script to discard `.note.gnu.property`

```
/DISCARD/ : {
    *(.note.gnu.property) 
}
```